# What's wrong with these code?

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec zip (lst:(int list) list) (lst2:int list)= match lst,lst2 with
|_,[]->lst
|[],_->[] (*never reach here*)
|(x::xs),(y::ys)->[x::y;(zip xs ys)]
```

Yup, [] is for all empty cases but another question.. why ocaml recognize x::y as int but not int list? It gives me the feedback that x::y has type int but required type int list

Answer (score 3):

The empty list `[]` is polymorphic, i.e., it's the same for every list type.

```
# [];;
- : 'a list = []
```

You can force a type by annotating the expression:

```
# ([] : int list list);;
- : int list list = []
#
```

**Update**

The `::` operator takes an element at the left and a list at the right. It looks like you're trying to apply it to two elements.

Comment: Thx very much.. question edited. Because I found the reason is not the empty int list list. Sorry for that

Comment: The `::` operator takes an element at the left and a list at the right. Not sure what result you want, but I suspect `x :: y` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If `x` comes from the front of an `int list list` value by destructuring, then it must be of type `int list`. If `y` comes from an `int list`, then it must be of type `int`.

Thus `x::y` should probably be `y::x` to get an `int list` as a result.

It seems you could get almost the same result with the following:

```
let zip = List.map2 (fun a b -> b::a)
```

although this function expects parameters as lists of the same length, whereas your code accommodates different lengths, and discards the extra elements from either lists.

Also, this function returns a "flat" list of lists, where yours tries to wrap the `int list`s in successive layers of lists, (like russian dolls). This will not type check, so you will have to think about how you can construct that list of list *without* using bracketed list expressions.

Answer (score 1):

To start, we first should look at the expected type of your generalized zip. If I understand correctly, you are given two arguments, where lst is a list of integer lists and lst2 is a list of integers. We now want to iterate both lists in parallel to append the current element of lst2 to the corresponding element in lst. This means, the result type of zip is the same as of lst, namely (int list) list.

Now if you return a list [ ... ], all its elements must be of type (int list). In particular the first element of this list, x::y, must have this type. Now lets look at the type of ::, the list constructor. It prepends an element to a list and returns the new one, so its type is 'a -> ('a list) -> ('a list). In the current situation, we expect a list of int as a result, so the concrete instance is int -> (int list) -> (int list). But you pass an x of type (int list) as first argument, that's where the error message comes from.

As the others have noted, if you prepend the element instead (y::x), the type of the first element is correct. If you really want to append, you can use List append x [y], but this worsens the computational complexity of your algorithm, since each list has to be iterated for the append.

As a last step, let's fix the rest of the list. The second argument is the result of zip with the type (int list) list. If you pack it into the outer list, the result type becomes ((int list) list) list which is incompatible with the first element and your expected result type. What you would like to do is to prepend the new list to the result of the recursion, i.e. you want to use the list constructor ::, not nested lists.

Your program then becomes:

```
let rec zip (lst:(int list) list) (lst2:int list)= match lst,lst2 with
|_,[]-> lst
|[],_->[] (*never reach here*)
|(x::xs),(y::ys)->
 (List.append x [y]) ::(zip xs ys)
```

which does the job:

```
# zip [[1;2];[3;4]] [7;8;9];;
- : int list list = [[1; 2; 7]; [3; 4; 8]]
```